# C# int to String ... output in Textbox

Tags: c#, string, int, calculator

I'm new to C#
and I was trying to code a small addition only calculator.

```
    int z = 0; //Meine Zahl
    // string b = 0; // Mein String

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = z + 1;
        textBox1.Text = a;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "2";
    }
...
```

my question is how do I fix it?

Comment: Use `textBox1.Text = a.ToString();`.

Comment: Dzenkuje Bardzo!

Comment: Nie ma za co....

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the `ToString()` method. You can call this method on every object you have and you can override the method as well; if needed.

In your button1_Click method use this

```
textBox1.Text = a.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

In general case, try using *formatting*; in case of C# 6.0+ *string interpolation*:

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       textBox1.Text = $"{z + 1}";
     }
```

In case of C# 5.0- `string.Format`:

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}", z + 1);
     }
```

Please, notice how it's easy to code and read:

```
     textBox1.Text = $"My old value is {z} and incremented one {z + 1}";
```